# how to add a new item in a customized listbox programmatically with c#

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

i have this customized listbox that i've created with Microsoft Expression Blend which contains three items (an image, a name and a text).. and this is the code of the ListBox Template!!

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
    <Grid Width="320" Height="80" Background="#FFCAE5DE">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Data="M8.4999981,6.8212103E-13 L256.5,6.8212103E-13 C261.19443,-1.8775456E-06 265,3.8055778 265,8.4999981 L265,55.499998 C265,60.194418 261.19443,63.999998 256.5,63.999998 L52.689537,63.999998 52.702888,75.988852 45.902157,63.999998 8.4999981,63.999998 C3.8055797,63.999998 0,60.194418 0,55.499998 L0,8.4999981 C0,3.8055778 3.8055797,-1.8775456E-06 8.4999981,6.8212103E-13 z" 
                          Fill="#FF3E977D" Height="Auto" Margin="5,5,8,-11" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stretch="Fill" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeDashCap="Round" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" 
                          StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.535" />
        <Border Margin="10,5,0,-2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="Auto" CornerRadius="4">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageURL}" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,0,-11">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Width="400" Margin="3,2,0,16" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Margin="0,47,43.5,-51" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Height="20" Margin="60,20,8,0" Width="Auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

as you can see, i have three bindings (ImageURL, Text and Name). Now what want to do is to implement a method in C# that allow me to add a new item in this listbox. And as a start i found some examples for adding lisboxitem with c# but i don't know how to apply it with my customized listbox... the method in c# was something like this!

```
private ListBoxItem AddItem(string imageUrl, string text, string name)
{ 
    ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
    /* the
       code
       of 
       the 
       customized
       ListBox */
     item.content = content;
     return item;
}
```

the question is, how can i add a new item in the customized listbox when i call the method `AddItem(imageUrl, text, name)` ?

Any Ideas..
Any help would be more than appreciated.

**@Margnus Johnansson** thanks a lot for the solution.
but still there one problem.. what if i want to add multiple items, what shall i do ?!!
this is the method that i've implemented..

```
public void Additem(string imageUrl, string text, string name)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> Items = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = Items;

        Items.Add(new Person() { Image = imageUrl, Text = text, Names = name });
    }
```

this method adds only one item even if i call it multiple times but my thing is that i want to add a new item in the listbox every time i call the method

```
Additem(string imageUrl, string, text, string name)
```

without overwriting the other items !!

thanks for understanding.

Comment: You shouldn't create an ObservableCollection inside your Add method. Put that global to the Page/Window in the constructor for example. This is the reason you see the problem you described, as you will resets and clear it every time you add an item. While you are at it, also move the assignment MyListBox.ItemsSource to outside as well (for example in you constructor or page load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really take a look at [Databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), it will help a lot.

The basics is that you create a model that represents an item:

```
public class MyItem
{
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then you create a bindable collection of these model items:

```
ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items{get;set;}
```

and bind your ListView to this collection:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
myListBox.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Finally, you can add items like this:

```
Items.Add(new MyItem() { ImageUrl = "http://..", Text = "My Text", Name = "My Name" });
```

Because of the powerful databinding, the ListBox should pickup the changes you have made to the collection, and you should see the new item in the ListBox.

Comment: wow man, that's genius !! that really works, but still one problem..what if i want to add multiple items ?!! what shall i do ?

Comment: I addressed your problem in a comment to your question.